# Rails Precompiling Assets failed - Errno::EROFS: Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having trouble deploying my app to heroku. I'm getting an EROFS error, which apparently means actionpack gem is trying to write to assets, which is read-only? Just a guess. I don't know what to do about it.

Here is Heroku's log showing the error:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        /tmp/build_b8b210e2045c2ea425a6220d0ba816ba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
remote:        Compiled jquery.js  (3ms)  (pid 2307)
...
remote:        Compiled application.css  (173ms)  (pid 2307)
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Errno::EROFS: Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /assets
remote:        /tmp/build_b8b210e2045c2ea425a6220d0ba816ba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:29:in `write_manifest'
remote:        /tmp/build_b8b210e2045c2ea425a6220d0ba816ba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:25:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_b8b210e2045c2ea425a6220d0ba816ba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
remote:        /tmp/build_b8b210e2045c2ea425a6220d0ba816ba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_b8b210e2045c2ea425a6220d0ba816ba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_b8b210e2045c2ea425a6220d0ba816ba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
remote:        /tmp/build_b8b210e2045c2ea425a6220d0ba816ba/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
```

Here is my Gemfile, if that helps

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'
gem "curb", "~> 0.8.4"


group :assets do
  #gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem "sass"#, "~> 3.2"
gem "haml", ">= 3.1.4"
gem "devise", ">= 2.1.0.rc"
gem "simple_form"
gem "nokogiri"

#make heroku not inject 2.3 plugins
gem "rails_12factor"
gem 'jquery-tablesorter', '~> 1.20', '>= 1.20.1'
#gem "datatables", :git => 'git://github.com/Caseproof/datatables.git'
gem "csv-mapper"
gem "lastfm"
gem "songkickr"
gem 'meta-tags', :require => 'meta_tags'
gem "geocoder"
group :development do
  gem "haml-rails", ">= 0.3.4", :group => :development
  gem "heroku", :group => :development
  # gem "powder", :git => "http://github.com/brookr/powder"
end


#gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
```

Comment: Did you change `config.serve_static_assets = true` in `config/application.rb`.

Comment: `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` run with this command.

Comment: That worked, Mohammad, thanks. So from now on I'll precompile assets instead of letting Heroku do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` run this command.It will solve your problem.